# Why doesn't cross join work in my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get the sum of inv.ServicePrice without using sum and group by but my query doesn't work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ServicesDetailedReport] 

        @FromDate date= '01-Jun-2010',
        @ToDate date= null

AS
BEGIN
        Set @ToDate= case when @ToDate IS NULL then Convert(varchar(11), getdate(), 106) else @ToDate end

        Select inv.InvoiceNo, inv.EntryDateTime, s.ServiceName, c.VehicleRegNo, inv.ServicePrice, c.CustomerName, inv.fk_BookingID
        from dbo.[Services] s
        inner join invoices inv
        on inv.fk_ServiceID= s.ServiceID
        inner join customers c
        on c.CustomerID= inv.fk_CustomerID
        Cross join (Select SUM(inc.ServicePrice) as TotalCost from dbo.Invoices inc as TotalCost) t
        where Convert(varchar(11), inv.EntryDateTime, 106) between @FromDate and @ToDate



END
```

Update:

```
**

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ServicesDetailedReport, Line 23
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

**

Comment: how is it not working ? can you explain further ? No result ? the result is wrong ?

Comment: Why do you convert your dates to string?

Comment: @Squirrel error updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
from dbo.Invoices inc as TotalCost
```

SQL Server will implicitly alias your table without `AS` keyword. So your query actually is treated as follows:

```
from dbo.Invoices AS inc AS TotalCost
                  ^      ^
                  |      |
                  |      |
                  |      |
```

Basically you're aliasing your table twice and this is invalid syntax.

So this would be updated and correct procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ServicesDetailedReport
    @FromDate DATE = '01-Jun-2010',
    @ToDate DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET @ToDate = ISNULL(@ToDate, GETDATE());

    SELECT inv.InvoiceNo, inv.EntryDateTime, s.ServiceName, c.VehicleRegNo, inv.ServicePrice, c.CustomerName, inv.fk_BookingID
    FROM dbo.services AS s
    INNER JOIN invoices AS inv
        ON inv.fk_ServiceID = s.ServiceID
    INNER JOIN customers AS c
        ON c.CustomerID = inv.fk_CustomerID
    CROSS JOIN (   SELECT SUM(inc.ServicePrice) AS TotalCost
                   FROM dbo.Invoices AS inc) AS t
    WHERE inv.EntryDateTime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate;
END;
```

Also note, that I replaced your case statement with a simple `ISNULL()` and removed redundant convert operators in your query, they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You alias twice and then use the first alias
Fix:

```
(Select SUM(inc.ServicePrice) as TotalCost from dbo.Invoices inc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'AS' used in 'as TotalCost' in cross join

```
  Select inv.InvoiceNo, inv.EntryDateTime, s.ServiceName, c.VehicleRegNo, inv.ServicePrice, c.CustomerName, inv.fk_BookingID
    from dbo.[Services] s
    inner join invoices inv
    on inv.fk_ServiceID= s.ServiceID
    inner join customers c
    on c.CustomerID= inv.fk_CustomerID
    Cross join (Select SUM(inc.ServicePrice) as TotalCost from dbo.Invoices inc ) t
    where Convert(varchar(11), inv.EntryDateTime, 106) between @FromDate and @ToDate
```